# ReaxtJS компонент секций, который обворачивает другие компоненты является умным?

Tags: reactjs, компоненты, create-react-app

```
function sectionContact() {
  return (
    <section class="section section-contact">
       <InfoContact />
       <FormContact />
    </section>
  );
}
```

Или же можно данный компонент так же засунуть в папку с презентационными(глупыми)?

Answer (score 0):

Обычно умными называют компоненты у которых есть свой state и они реализуют внутри себя некоторую логику.

В Вашем примере идет просто вывод.
Такой компонент обычно называют презентационным.